# Android Studio 2.2.1 Error: java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I've updated my android studio to `2.2.1` and now I'm receiving error message in message section of android studio

**Error:**

> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

Here is a [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgbOf.png) of my android studio:

Help me regarding this what to do now.

Comment: clean project and remove studio cache

Answer (score 4):

In the root folder of your project, delete the `.gradle` folder.

C:\Users\VipinSaini\AndroidStudioProjects\MyProject\.gradle

then reboot Android Studio

Comment: on MAC , do not have .gradle folder, what should i do ?

Comment: @aznelite89 You have it, but you have to set finder to show hidden files to see it, or do it from the Terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your project, there's ".gradle" folder. Delete it and restart Android Studio
and immediately rebuild the project.
                               or
Go to your project, there's ".idea" folder in this folder delete libraries folder and restart Android Studio
and immediately rebuild the project.

Answer (score 1):

@aznelite89,

> Just delete the .gradle folder from the project directory. It is
>   hidden in MacOS. Restart the Android Studio. Fixed, continue your work
>   :)

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Project Location and removed .gradle folder.

Answer (score 1):

Iv'e ran into this problem and deleting the gradle folder **didn't work** for me.
I was getting `NullPointerException: null` with no further explanation in `Event log` whenever I tried to debug.

After looking at the call stack of the exception, what eventually worked was pressing the `Sync project with gradle files` button:

[image]